# How to pass variables to mpdf?

Tags: variables, yii2, mpdf

I want to pass variables **$name** and **$age** from my controller to mpdf view page.
However, it gives me an error: **Undefined variable: name**.

I tried to pass data in three ways:
1) Created separate methods in Controller **getName()** and **getAge()** and call them in a view

2) Send the variables while rendering the page

3) trying to query the age and name from Database directly from view.

All three ways didn't give result. 1 and 3 leads to not loaded page and the second one shows  **Undefined variable: name** error.

**View:**

```
<div><?= $name; ?></div>
```

P.S. I also tried to do like:

```
<div><?echo $name; ?></div>
<div><?php $name; ?></div>
```

**Controller:**

```
public function actionIndex(){
  $this->actionCreateMPDF();
  $a =  Profile::find('age')->where(['user_id'=>\Yii::$app->user->id])->asArray()->one();
  $age = $a['age'];

  $n =  Profile::find('name')->where(['user_id'=>\Yii::$app->user->id])->asArray()->one();     
  $name = $n['name'];
  return $this->render('index',[
    'age'  => $age,
    'name' => $name,
  ]);
}

public function actionCreateMPDF(){
  $b = true;
  $mpdf = new mPDF();
  $mpdf->WriteHTML($this->renderPartial('index'));
  $mpdf->showImageErrors = true;
  $mpdf->Output();
  exit; 
}
```

If anyone knows what is my problem please help me :3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to pass variables to function `actionCreatePdf()`

```
public function actionIndex(){
    $profileData = Profile::find()
        ->select(['age', 'name'])
        ->where(['user_id'=>\Yii::$app->user->id])
        ->one();

    $age = $profileData->age;
    $name = $profileData->name;

    $this->actionCreateMPDF($age, $name);
    return $this->render('index',[
        'age'  => $age,
        'name' => $name,
    ]);
}

public function actionCreateMPDF($age, $name){
    $b = true;
    $content = $this->renderPartial('index',[
        'age'  => $age,
        'name' => $name,
    ]);

    $mpdf = new mPDF();
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($content);
    $mpdf->showImageErrors = true;
    $mpdf->Output();
    exit;
}
```